# How to retrieve the text of only one div with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, this

The div with class `click-me` contains two strings of text `Bronze Level` and `Active`. When the div is clicked some actions will be performed based on the div that is being clicked. I know which div is clicked with `$(this).html()` and get the texts with `$(this).text()`. If I wish to retrieve only one string at the time `on click`, how can I achieve this?

By the way, I know how to retrieve texts from div in jQuery. That is NOT the question. I wish to know how to get the strings separately from `var serviceblockdiv`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.click-me').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            
             //get the text of div you clicked
           var serviceblockdiv = $(this).text(); 
           
           //log div text clicked
           console.log(serviceblockdiv);
   })
      });
```

```css
.click-me{
border : solid 15px green;
width: 50%;
cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-3 click-me">
              <div class="dashboard-web-service-name">Bronze Level</div>
              <div class="dashboard-web-service-status">Active</div>
         </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$(this).children(":nth-child(1)").text()` to select the first child then `:nth-child(2)` for the second and so on.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.click-me').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //get the text of div you clicked
    var serviceblockdiv1 = $(this).children(":nth-child(1)").text();
    var serviceblockdiv2 = $(this).children(":nth-child(2)").text();
    console.log(serviceblockdiv1)
    console.log(serviceblockdiv2);
   
  })
});
```

```css
.click-me {
  border: solid 15px green;
  width: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-3 click-me">
  <div class="dashboard-web-service-name">Bronze Level</div>
  <div class="dashboard-web-service-status">Active</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use `$(this).children(":nth-child(1)").text()` selector instead..check the updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Consider either checking the originalTarget from the event object "e" instead.

Or, even simpler, just change your selector from ".click-me" to ".click-me > div".

By changing the selector, you will attach the handler to each of the div elements within .click-me, instead of the parent which contains them both.  It seems to be what you're trying to do.

Comment: Okay. I just tried ".click-me > div". While this is good, it is not necessarily what I'm wanting to do. Your solution will display one text based on where the user clicks. If clicks near the first text, first text will show in the console. If he clicks at bottom, second text will show. But I need a more bulletproof solution.

Comment: If you're referring to being able to click empty space instead of the text, and yet it still triggers... It's because a <div> by default takes 100% of the container width, even if the text is smaller.  You can change this with CSS.  Or wrap the text inside <span> and make the selector ".click-me > div > span".

Comment: Yeah in other cases it would be a great solution but that's not what I'm referring to. I'm just wanting to split the string var serviceblockdiv and get each text separately AFTER they have clicked.